# Avoid hacking with folder has CHMOD is 777

Tags: permissions, chmod

Our website was hacked due the fact a folder had 777 permissions which means people can upload files there and run scripts remotely. However, the folder needs to be 777 as the site got a client feature to crop images, and need to save the cropped images there.

How can I secure this folder and prevent hacking?

Please show me how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does it need to be 777? Why not 755? Also, are you checking for valid images?

Comment: Client have the script that crop the image run, we need 777 folder and no way we can't change it.

Comment: A folder set to 777 is NOT automatically open to the public for them to upload files and run scripts. But it will allow anyone with SSH or command line access to do so (perhaps other users on the server) and if you have vulnerabilities in web applications (e.g. WordPress) then they may be able to upload files that way. This is a common source of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider your design.  You should restrict the client to reading and executing (but not writing to) a script that you have written yourself to do the specific task they need.  In the script verify that you are operating upon an image file so it can't be used on other files that are not valid images.  Do more than just checking the file extension, also check the first several bytes of the file (which for most formats will tell you what it is).  File extensions are easily changed.

Never let a user upload their own scripts for execution to your server.  Hacking you will be really easy if you do that.  If you have "power" users that must be able to do this, create for them their own user account that is sandboxed to their own environment.  This way they can't affect other users or your system, and you have non-repudiation on their actions (so if they do something stupid you can hold them accountable), and any security holes they open up will be limited to destroying their files and not yours.

Answer (score 0):

CHMOD 777 is inherently unsafe. It's only used to temporarily avoid issues when installing scripts. After installing scripts, you CHMOD it back to something like 755. To secure it, you will have to change the access to something other than wide open.

To have a user crop an image I would recommend a conventional javascript cropper like [Jcrop](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/)

Comment: It's not inherently unsafe if you trust all other accounts on your server (such as your own private VPS). And sometimes this is (unfortunately) necessary for various apps to have write access to folders.