# Can't access to SQLite3 database from php

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

Lately I've been struggling with a problem and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I want to add information to a database in SQLite3 from a PHP script. To achieve that since I am new to this I created a database, put some info in there and with the following script I am able to read the data:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('mydatabase.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM temps');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Next step I tried to ADD info to the database from PHP with this script:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('mydatabase.db');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO temps (zone,temperature) VALUES ('maia',66)");
echo "something";
}
?>
```

This script does NOT add anything to the database and the echo is displayed.

After reading a bit I changed the last script to something like this:

```
<?php
try
{
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydatabase.db');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO temps (zone,temperature) VALUES ('maia',66)");
echo "Row Inserted\n";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
        print $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

There is no exception displayed, the echo "Row Inserted" is displayed and nothing is added to the database.

Can someone give me an hint about what am I missing please?

Pretty much appreciated.

Comment: Does this INSERT work when you run it from sqlite console?

Comment: Works perfect in the console

Comment: Do you run the script through Apache in web or as a user?

Comment: Web. Im accessing the link where the php is via browser

Comment: Try to allow everybody to write into your database file and into the folder where the file is located. Cause apache user may not have a right to write into the database.

Comment: Bit of a long shot.. does the user which is connecting to the database have the correct permissions?  Ie to insert?

Comment: @user4035 should you not find out which user apache is running as and give said user permission. Rather using the everyone?  Or chmod 777?

Comment: I'm new at this but I think you're asking about the chmod right? Everything right now is 777.

Comment: @CarlosMontanha Does it work after chmod?

Comment: Why did you set 777?

Comment: It was on 777 since the beginning. I placed it 777 when I created it for test purposes

Comment: @CarlosMontanha Did you chmod the parent directory of the file to 777?

Comment: Before you go making your entire folder(s) 777. Please.. please take note on the following question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994975/avoid-hacking-with-folder-has-chmod-is-777

Comment: Its a raspberry pi running raspbian and 0 information on it.

Comment: @user4035 I did not. I chmod the files not the directory.

Comment: @CarlosMontanha Can you try to chmod the dir to 777. It's unsecure, but for testing we can do it.

Comment: @user4035 just tried 777 the folder and it worked. Thank you very very much. Now is there a way to keep this "safer" and not having the folder at 777 and the files at 777?
Thanks in advance